# "Cannot find module" when executing 'npm start'[How should I approach my error?]

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I want to host my website using node.js.
After `npm install express --save`, and adding `package-lock.json` & `package.json` & `Procfile` & `node_module` & `.env`.

I have tried this below, but not worked.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

What other approaches should I do? The following is my error.

```
> portfolio-website@1.0.0 start /Users/John/Project/portfolio-website
> node server

module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/John/Project/portfolio-website/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:190:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:662:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio-website@1.0.0 start: `node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio-website@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/John/.npm/_logs/2019-01-21T00_09_21_588Z-debug.log
```

`server` folder includes `server.js`.
First of all, why cannot module be found? The order of path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the `server.js` file is inside `server` folder, then you should run `node server/server.js`